# Execute multiple statements inside conditional operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, conditional-rendering

I want to render 2 arrays, 1st array being rendered on top of the second, inside a conditional operator and don't want to concatenate the arrays which has duplicate elements.

```
someCondition ? (
   arr1.map(elm => renderItem(elm)),
   arr2.map(elm => renderItem(elm))
) : null
```

However, this only renders the 2nd array ignoring the 1st one.

Also, don't want to concatenate the two arrays and then filter the elements from the joined array as 2nd array can be very large at times.

Comment: "this seems to only render the second array ignoring the first array" That's what the comma operater does. It evaluates the first expression, *discards* its value, then evaluates the second expression and returns that value as the expression result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially use [React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) here:

```
someCondition ? (
   <>
      {arr1.map(elm => renderItem(elm))}
      {arr2.map(elm => renderItem(elm))}
   </>
) : null
```

Comment: Yep, this worked. I only had to add the curly brackets to each statement if anyone else runs into this issue.